The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread MAUI multi platfrom app
I want to launch my MAUI windows application via command-line. When I try to do that I am getting this error which freeze launch screen. I did this for Xamarin Forms windows application and it works.
Error

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called
an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
The Application Object must initially be accessed from the
multi-thread apartment.'

You can create a new MAUI Multi Platform template app and add these to the WinUI project's appxmanifest.
Package.appxmanifest
  xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap uap5">

    <Applications>
        <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
            <uap:VisualElements
              DisplayName="MauiApp3"
              Description="MauiApp3"
              BackgroundColor="transparent"
              Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
              Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png">
                <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
                <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
            </uap:VisualElements>
            <Extensions>
                <uap5:Extension
                Executable="MauiApp3.WinUI.exe"
                EntryPoint="MauiApp3.WinUI.App"
                Category="windows.appExecutionAlias">
                    <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
                        <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="maui33.exe" />
                    </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
                </uap5:Extension>
            </Extensions>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
    
    <Capabilities>
        <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    </Capabilities>


Can your application be deployed directly to the Windows platform via Visual studio and run properly?

Yes I can. This is just a fresh MAUI multi platform template. Above code was the only change I have done. I even tried uap3:Extension

I could reproduce this problem, and I resolved this problem by replacing the following code:
 EntryPoint="MauiApp3.WinUI.App"

with:
 EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication"

